# Proving this complicated curve is differentiable

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I want to prove this curve below is differentiable at $t=0$:

> $\alpha\left(t\right) = \left\{
>      \begin{array}{lr}
>        (t,0,e^{-1/t^2}),& if\ t>0 \\
>        (t,e^{-1/t^2},0),& if\ t< 0\\
> (0,0,0),& if\ t=0\
>      \end{array}
>    \right.\\$

**My solution**

We might define $\alpha$ as $\alpha(t)=(t,h(t),g(t))$, where

> $h\left(t\right) = \left\{
>      \begin{array}{lr}
>        e^{-1/t^2},& if\ t<0 \\
> 0,& if\ t\ge 0\
>      \end{array}
>    \right.\\$
>
> $g\left(t\right) = \left\{
>      \begin{array}{lr}
>        e^{-1/t^2},& if\ t>0 \\
> 0,& if\ t\le0\
>      \end{array}
>    \right.\\$

Using the limit definition of the derivatives, we have $h'(0)=g'(0)=0$, then

$\alpha'(0)=(1,0,0)$ and $\alpha$ is differentiable at $t=0$.

So is my solution correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct. You have to check for each element in $\alpha(t)=(t,h(t),g(t))$ that the derivative exists by evaluating the left and right limits. Both are equal to 1 for $t$ and both equal $0$ for $h$ and $g$. You can extend the methods you would use in $\mathbb{R}$ to this triple $\in \mathbb{R}^3$.